# Backbone.js - fetch data and display

Tags: backbone.js

I'm just beginning out on Backbone.js. Here's my code.

```
$(function(){

    //Backbone Model
    var Cat = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    // create a collection
    var CatCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Cat,
        url: 'http://localhost/cats/index.php/cats/index'
    });
    var catCollection = new CatCollection();
    catCollection.fetch();

    // Backbone view
    var CatView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#contents"),
        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.el.html(catCollection);
        }
    });

    var catView = new CatView();
});
```

What I am doing is.

1. Create a backbone model
2. Create a collection using the model I created.
3. Fetch data from MySQL database - this returns a JSON data object.
4. Display the fetched data in the div "#contents".

On google Chrome, I can see that the "fetch()" method works, because I can see my JSON object returned as

```
[{"id":"1","name":"stella","age":"5"},{"id":"2","name":"Max","age":"2"}]
```

But if I do "alert(catCollection)" after the fetch, it displays "[object] [object]".

What is the best way of displaying this?

Comment: I've been struggling to learn Backbone too. I don't have an answer for you, just an observation: it seems to me that your             this.el.html(catCollection) line isn't going to work, because you haven't supplied a template or anything to render that collection.

Comment: alert(catCollection.toJSON())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the templates in JST array.

```
$(this.el).html($(JST["comments/item"](model.toJSON())));
```

"comments\item" is the template path and name
If you are using Rails, just use the Jammit and write templates with ERB (default) or Jade

Answer (score 1):

The backbone.js documentation give an example like so:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(catCollection));
```

http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON

Answer (score -9):

Use [console.log](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/console.html).

Comment: I have been using console.log to print out values. But I want to know the proper way of displaying data to the view.